# How do I add HTML links in C# TextBox?

Tags: c#, html, textbox, hyperlink

How can I put a link in a C# `TextBox`?  I have tried to put HTML tags in the box but instead of showing a link it shows the entire HTML tag.  Can this be done with a `TextBox`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would think about this a little bit. If you allow executable code in an editable control, the user, the user can execute **ANY** code. This is generally a bad idea.

The behavior of the C# control is intentional to prevent the exact behavior that you are trying to create. A little creativity (such as parsing out links from the text box and creating a list of links next or below the text box) will provide a much safer application.

Answer (score 7):

Use the [RichTextBox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f591a55w.aspx), no need to build your own, it cames with VS

Answer (score 2):

I would try using an editable div and making it look like a text box. This would allow you to get user input and use links.

To make this easier, try [JEditable](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable).

Answer (score 2):

If that is in windows forms and you really can't use the richtextbox, you can create a control with a linklabel inside of textbox.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/LinkTextBox.aspx

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge not with the standard textbox.  You'd have to create your own.  One option it the [Telerik](http://www.telerik.com/) controls, they're a little pricey for individual development, but very robust and configurable.

Answer (score 0):

For windows application, we can use a webbrowser control. However, for web applications Freetextbox will do the job.This is freely available dll.